# scala- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, dependencies, sbt

I want to run this project: [Lambda-Arch-Spark](https://github.com/knoldus/Lambda-Arch-Spark) (developed with Scala)

- I am running Windows 10.
- I installed Scala V2.11.8 and sbt V0.13.17 (the same versions which had been used by the developer).
- Then I configured the required tools -servers- (i do not have any problem with the tools) .
- The project has 5 main programs (after running the `sbt run` command, you need to choose which program to run)

I ran the 2nd: `CassandraKafkaConsumer` and 3rd: `TwitterStreamApp`  without any errors but the 5th:`SparkStreamingKafkaConsumer` gave me `NoClassDefFoundError` error (also the 1st `BatchProcessor` gave me `NoClassDefFoundError`)
as the following:

```
[info] Running com.knoldus.speed.SparkStreamingKafkaConsumer
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/DStream
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/DStream
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed 9 mai 2018 11:47:29
```

I tried the project in many other computers and the same errors was
reproduced.